# Load tabLayout fragments in background

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

I'm using a TabLayout which contains a couple of fragments.
I used to set the OffScreenPageLimit to the maximum so it would load all fragments before displaying the activity. This gets me smooth animations but because i continue adding more fragments the initial loading time starts getting too long.

Is there a way to start the activity with just one fragment/tab in memory and then load the rest of them in a background thread?
The user always takes a second or two before switching tabs anyway. Would it help to switch to ViewPager2?

```
ViewPager viewPager =  (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
MyFragmentPagerAdapter myFragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
viewPager.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(myFragmentPagerAdapter.getCount());
//viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Comment: If you want smooth animations, it's not necessary (or advisable) to load all fragments at once. For example, I have a ViewPager with pretty heavy fragments and I only load one fragment on each side. Never had a problem with the swipe animation. About ViewPager2, I would stay away from it until this issue gets resolved: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150626937